# Hide certain toolbar icons on the side of KDE Plasma's task manager?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, 21.10

[I FOUND IT OUT MYSELF, ANSWERED]

I want to hide certain toolbar icons, like NoMachine, Bluetooth (the icon in blue, next to Discord), Most Recent Device, etc. The icons are taking up most of my task manager and I tend to use a bunch of space on the left with pinned and open programs, like terminal and wine. Is there a way? I am using regular Ubuntu, but with the KDE Plasma desktop. Thanks!

[Link shows an image with a mess of toolbar icons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDYvm.png)

Update: I figured it out myself, I right clicked on the blank space and clicked Edit Panel, I hovered over the System Tray and hit configure on the popup menu, then clicked the bell with Edit Entries and configured it the way I liked it.

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer in the textbox below. Do not post the answer within the question

Answer (score 1):

Right next to the system tray icons there is a little arrow pointing upwards. Right-click on that arrow and select **Configure System Tray…**.

[image: Screenshot of the right-click menu]

It will open a window where you can configure each one of the **Entries**.

[image: Screenshot of the System Tray Settings window]